# Exact solution of a class of interacting QFTs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, renormalization, path-integral

Consider a Euclidean quantum field theory, whose action only has derivative terms. For example, for a simple scalar field, consider
$$S[\phi]=\int\mathrm{d}^d{x}\ \mathrm{P}_{2n}[\partial\phi], \tag{1}$$
where $\mathrm{P}_{2n}[\partial\phi]$ is an arbitrary polynomial of degree $2n$. The $(\partial\phi)^2$ term is what we'd call the usual kinetic terms, and the rest are increasingly more irrelevant terms. For well-definedness of some of the calculations below I will assume that the coefficient of the highest order term is positive. If necessary I'm also willing to drop all odd terms, though I don't think it's a huge issue.

Let's now consider the path integral for this theory
$$Z = \int \mathcal{D}\phi\ \exp(-S[\phi]),$$
and do the change of variables $A=\partial\phi$<sup>$(*)$</sup>. Then we have
$$Z = \int \mathcal{D}A\ \frac{\mathcal{D}\phi}{\mathcal{D}A}\ \exp(-S[A]).$$
But it holds that
$$\frac{\mathcal{D}\phi}{\mathcal{D}A} = \frac{1}{\mathrm{det}\,\partial} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathrm{det}\,\partial^2}},$$
up to, zero-mode issues and possibly, regularization issues, which are not hugely important at this point (I could be more careful if necessary to deal with those, but I don't think it's important for now). The rest of the path integral is now a path integral of a theory with no derivatives, so it reduces to an infinite product of regular convergent integrals,
$$\int \mathcal{D}A \exp\!\left(-\int\mathrm{d}^d x\; \mathrm{P}_{2n}[A]\right) = \prod_x \left(\int \mathrm{d}A(x) \exp\!\left(-\mathrm{P}_{2n}[A(x)]\right)\right)=:Z_0,$$
where I possibly need to regularize the infinite product in the end.

All in all we end up with, what we'd call a one-loop determinant $Z_1:=\left(\det\partial^2\right)^{-1/2}$ and $Z_0$, having, thus, fully solved the theory:
$$Z=Z_0\; Z_1\tag{2}$$
getting a manifestly finite answer.

Generalizing, one could imagine replacing $\mathrm{P}_{2n}[\partial \phi]$ by an arbitrary positive definite function of $\partial \phi$. One cute choice would be $\sqrt{\mathrm{det}(\partial\phi\otimes\partial\phi)}$ giving the Nambu-Goto action. All of the above arguments also work in this case.

I strongly suspect there is something wrong with my argumentation! For one, this gives - albeit just conceptually - an explicit prescription to quantize the Nambu-Goto action, which, is famously difficult (and hence we resort to quantizing the Polyakov action in string theory). But also, just looking at the action (1) (with $n\to\infty$), it includes an infinite tower of ever-more irrelevant terms, hence one would assume it is UV-divergent, but the result (2) is finite, hence the theory is UV-finite.

*Where is the catch?*

---

<sup><sup>$(*)$</sup> I've suppressed indices to not clutter the notation, but everything should work when restoring indices. Alternatively one should look at it through a differential form lense</sup>

Comment: By setting $\partial \phi  = A$ you show that your theory has no dynamics. i.e. where is the propagator?

Comment: @Oбжорoв That's precisely the issue, an allowed change of path-integration variables, reduces a theory that seems to have dynamics to one that doesn't have (and hence it's exactly solvable). This change of variables is sometimes used to solve BF or CS-like theories, but there the result is not surprising because it's a topological theory. It is also implicitly used when you are rigorously defining gauge theories through differential cohomology.

Comment: Are you sure this theory is well posed? If one considers a toy 3-site lattice model with periodic connections, $p(\mathbf{v}) \propto \exp(-(v_1-v_2)^2/2 - (v_2-v_3)^2/2 - (v_3 - v_1)^2)$, this probability distribution is not normalizable on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (you can do two of the integrals and get a finite result, but the last diverges). If you add a quadratic term in any one of the variables, then you get a finite result. I suspect the same issue occurs when you generalize to $N$ sites and take the continuum limit, at least in 1 spatial dim -- not sure if higher dimensions would save it.

Comment: @bbrink Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure how to translate your lattice model to my continuum QFT. What would it correspond to in terms of the $\mathrm{P}_{2n}$? Also what do you mean by adding a quadratic term? All the terms in your exponent are quadratic. But, regardless, I can put that theory on a compact manifold instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and all probabilities should be fine.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): If $d>1$ then there are more $A_{\mu}$ fields than $\phi$ fields, and the Jacobian $\frac{\mathcal{D}\phi}{\mathcal{D}A}$ is singular.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll write this as an answer instead of a series of comments, though it may not fully answer the question. My original comment considered a special case of the following model.

Consider the following (non-quantum) lattice model of $N$ sites and lattice spacing $a$ for a set of variables $\phi_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $i = 1, \dots, N$:

$$p(\phi) \propto \exp\left( - \sum_{i=1}^N\left\{ \frac{\rho a}{2} \left(\frac{\phi_{i} - \phi_{i-1}}{a} \right)^2 + \frac{k a}{2} \phi_i^2\right\}\right).$$
For now, let me consider a system with periodic boundary conditions, $\phi_{i+N} = \phi_i$.

In the continuum limit $N \rightarrow \infty$, $a \rightarrow 0$, $Na = L$, we take $i/N \rightarrow x \in (0, L]$, $\phi_i \rightarrow \phi(x)$, and $(\phi_{i+1} - \phi_i)/a \rightarrow \phi'(x)$. i.e., this is a 1-dimensional model. The resulting action would be
$$S[\phi] = \int_0^L dx~\left\{ \frac{\rho}{2} \left(\phi'(x) \right)^2 + \frac{k}{2} \phi(x)^2\right\},$$
with $\phi(x + L) = \phi(x)$. If $k = 0$, this would correspond to $P_{2}(\partial \phi)$ in OP's notation. I'll just focus on this quadratic model, since it should be sufficient to illustrate my point.

Let me return to the lattice model for now. In my original comment I considered $k = 0$, $\rho = 1$, $a = 1$, and $N = 3$, and pointed out that if one integrates $\phi = (\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3)$ over $\mathbb{R}^3$ the probability density is not normalizable when $k = 0$. You could try to save this by restricting the values the $\phi$'s take to some finite range, but placing bounds on the $\phi$'s is like adding some very nonlinear terms to the action in order to drive the probably to zero when $\phi$ exceeds the desired bounds, and the resulting action cannot really be thought of as a function of just $\partial \phi$ in this case.

We can see this in the general case by attempting to change variables to the lattice derivative. Let $A_i = (\phi_i - \phi_{i-1})/a$ for $i = 2, \dots, N$ and $A_1 = (\phi_1 - \phi_N)/a$ (due to the periodic boundary conditions). Then, $\partial A_i /\partial \phi_j = (\delta_{ij} - \delta_{i-1,j})/a$, $i = 2, \dots, N$ and $\partial A_1/\partial \phi_j = (\delta_{1,j} - \delta_{N,j})/a$. In matrix form this Jacobian looks like
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial \phi} = \frac{1}{a} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &\dots & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & 
 & & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1\end{bmatrix};$$
i.e., ones on the diagonal, $-1$ on the lower diagonal, except in the last column in which there is a $-1$ in the top row. This matrix has determinant $0$, as can be seen, e.g., by sequentially adding each row to the one above it--- eventually you will find that the top two rows differ by a factor of $-1$. Thus, this transformation is singular for the $1d$ lattice ring, and the model is not well-defined when $k = 0$.

It's also instructive to try to calculate $\partial \phi/\partial A$ instead of $\partial A/\partial \phi$ (either one works if the jacobian determinant is non-zero). To do so we need to solve for $\phi_i$ in terms of the $A_i$. We can rewrite our definition of $A_i$ as $\phi_{i+1} = \phi_1 + a A_i$, which is a recursion relation with solution $\phi_{i} = \phi_1 + a \sum_{j=2}^i A_j$. If we set $i = N$ we get $0 = \phi_1 - \phi_N + a\sum_{j=2}^N A_j = a \sum_{j=1}^N A_j$, which shows that the $A_i$'s are not independent --- which manifests as the singularity in $\partial A/\partial \phi$.

This singularity results from the periodic boundary condition. We might try to save the model, at least in 1 spatial dimension, by considering a chain instead.

But, to do that we need to decide what happens to the $((\phi_i - \phi_{i-1})/a)^2$ term for $i = 1$. One option is to just leave it out. We could then define $A_i = (\phi_i - \phi_{i-1})/a$ as before, but only for $i = 2, \dots, N$, and $\phi_1$ would have to be left on its own and not part of the transformation. The matrix $\partial A/\partial \phi$ would then have $1$'s along the diagonal and $-1$ on the lower diagonal, but no pesky $-1$ in the top right corner. The matrix has determinant $1/a^{N-1}$, so the change of variables is ok. But then the normalization integral becomes
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\phi_1 d\phi_2 \dots d\phi_N ~\exp\left( - \sum_{i=2}^N\left\{ \frac{\rho a}{2} \left(\frac{\phi_{i} - \phi_{i-1}}{a} \right)^2\right\}\right) = a^{N-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\phi_1 \int_{-\infty}^\infty dA_2 \dots dA_N ~ \exp\left( - \sum_{i=1}^N\left\{ \frac{\rho a}{2} \left(A_i\right)^2\right\}\right)$$
which is not normalizable because the action does not depend on $\phi_1$, which must still be integrated over. In order to render the integral finite, we must supply a boundary condition to fix $\phi_1$, such as by multiplying the exponential by a delta function $\delta(\phi_1 - c)$ for the desired boundary value $c$. More generally, one could let the value of $\phi_1$ fluctuate, by demanding it be distributed according to some normalizable distribution. Either way, this explicitly adds $\phi_1$ dependence to the action, so it is not purely a function of derivatives of the fields.

Note that these results do not depend on the fact that the model is only Gaussian in the $A_i$; adding higher order terms will not fix the fact that the transformation is singular or not normalizable unless some explicit dependence on at least one $\phi_i$ is introduced.

**tl;dr:** a lattice model that would formally limit to a path integral (on a bounded spatial domain) with only derivative terms is not normalizable/singular unless one introduces constraints on the individual fields. According to Qmechanic's comment, this is not improved in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not address my question. It also has many problems. Its main problem is that it declares that a free massless scalar ($\mathrm{P}_2[\partial\phi]$) is not a well-defined QFT. Big, if true. But at the moment it's, at best, a questionable statement. (1/3)

Comment: Moreover the singularity in the conitnuum version of your Jacobian is precisely the zero-mode that I was explicitly cavalier about in my question. $\phi=c$ (constant) has zero derivative so the transformation will be singular. You should remove that. That's how it's usually done. You're still left with the integral over the zero mode in the end. So you have $\int \mathrm{d}c \mathcal{D}A \frac{\mathcal{D}'\phi}{\mathcal{D}A} \cdots$. In your chain version it's the same. Now you see explicitly that it's a zero mode integral. It's exactly the leftover $\phi$ integral. (2/3)

Comment: You can regularize that by giving $\phi$ a finite target space, or you can just remove this volume altogether in the definition of the partition function. Path integrals are, anyways, defined up to a normalization, which you can fix once and for all. Finally the (correct and helpful) comment by @Qmechanic is unrelated. In $d=1$ (which your lattice model takes place) the transformation is well-defined. (3/3)